# Is taking back insurance money (ignoring the interest) permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, money, insurance

My father payed for life insurance for 15 years now, not knowing that it is haram. After 15 years can he take back the amount he payed to the insurance company, ignoring the interest money? Will it be halal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as insurance is considered haram because of the presence of riba/interest in it.

And about interest Allah says in quran:

> “Those who eat riba will not stand (on the Day of Resurrection) except
>   like the standing of a person beaten by Shaytan (Satan) leading him to
>   insanity…
>
> O you who believe! Be afraid of Allah and **give up what remains (due to
>   you) from riba (from now onwards) if you are (really) believers**.
>
> And if you do not do it, then take a notice of war from Allah and His
>   Messenger.”
>
> [2:275, 278-279]

So, you must leave every penny of interest but taking back YOUR money is absolutely ok. For further reading, read [this](https://islamqa.info/en/60185).

### Allah knows best

Comment: I think uncertainty (gharar) also plays a role in the fiqh on insurances.

Comment: Yes, their are also other factors, but this is major factor and ruling on money is always to keep whats your and leave whats interest.